# How do I rename files using the directory name?

Tags: bash, files, rename, string

My file structure now is:

- Input

  - 1

    - pre.nii
  - 2

    - pre.nii

I would like it to be:

- Input

  - 1_pre.nii
  - 2_pre.nii

From the Input folder, I tried: `for i in */pre.nii; do echo $i_pre.nii; done`

But that gave me:

```
    .nii
    .nii
```

I also tried: `for i in */pre.nii; do echo ${i%/*}; done`
that gave me:

```
    1
    2
```

But I couldn't figure out how to use the `%` string operator and add the correct suffix.

Comment: underscore is a valid part of a bash variable; try ${i}_pre.nii ...

Comment: @JeffSchaller That also worked: `for i in */pre.nii; do echo mv ${i} ${i%/*}_pre.nii; done`.  So, for the suffix to be added after a string operator, it should be outside the curly brackets. Is that correct?

Comment: yes; the [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) is delineated by the braces ${...}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace one `/` (escaped with `\`) by `_`:

```
for i in */pre.nii; do echo mv "$i" "${i/\//_}"; done
```

If everything looks fine, remove `echo`.

Comment: Thank you!

To make sure I understand: You used the string operator `"${i/old/new}"` but to use `/` as `old` you had to escape it with \

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use sed to do the replacement and test before making changes:

```
for i in */pre.nii;
do 
   j=$(echo $i | sed 's/\//_/')
   echo $j
done
```

then run it

```
for i in */pre.nii;
do 
   j=$(echo $i | sed 's/\//_/')
   mv -v $i $j
done
```

Comment: Maybe this will be easier to read: `sed 's|/|_|'` instead of the backspaced `sed 's/\//_/'`